# How to read a file as varbinary data?

Tags: php

I am just trying to read a file as a string then am converting that into hex decimal then pushing that data into the varbinary field in DB. The problem is when am trying to open a file its showing invalid data.

```
$filname=$_FILES["upload"]["name"] ;
$filesize=filesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
$contents=file_get_contents($_FILE['upload']['tmp_name]);
$value='0x'.strtoupper($value);
```

this is my snippet so while storing it causing the problem

Comment: Why are you saving the file contents in the DB?  Usually I find it better to just save a link to the file.  As your DB size grows, you'll find saving the entire file contents to be prohibitive.

Comment: So, what does your code look like? You need to show us what you've tried. Other than that, I agree with @ArtisticPhoenix. Don't save file contents in the DB unless you, for some very specific reason, need to. You should also read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: learned that lesson trying to import a 250GB DB that was 99% of the size in image files ... lol

Comment: In our organization they are storing file into database.am pushing my file into database through PHP.but they are downloading through the vb.net code so ita showing error

Comment: You still need to show us your code, though. We can't sit here and guess what's going on with it. Btw, why are you converting the binary file data as hex before you store it in the DB in a varbinary field? Shouldn't you just store the binary data as is?

Comment: $filname=$_FILES["upload"]["name"] ; $filesize=filesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']) ;$contents=file_get_contents($_FILE['upload']['tmp_name]); $value='0x'.strtoupper($value);  this is my snippet so while storing it causing problem

Comment: Post your code in your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`'0x'.strtoupper($value)` doesn't magically represent the content of `$value` using a hexadecimal notation.

You need to use a function that knows how to represent each byte of your value using the hexadecimal notation and that PHP function is [`bin2hex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php). If the language of the database you use needs the `0x` prefix in front of the data (probably to know that the data is represented in the hexadecimal representation) then your code should be like:

```
 $value = '0x'.bin2hex($content);
```

Comment: I added that line too forgot to mention there